# XML search for a node from an array and add new data to a new node

Tags: php, xml, nodes

From this tutorial - section on Adding nodes over at PHPFreaks, I did post over there but have had no replies strange as the tutorial was written by them.

http://www.phpfreaks...ndling-xml-data

When I use my xml file it creates the node but does not insert the new data. There are no page errors. I'm sure I have just missed something very simple and after hours of trying I will now bow down and ask for help.

***This is the script I'm using***

```
<?php
// isbn => pages
$page_numbers = array(
                     '1234' => '654', // insert data into catparent node
                     '5678' => '789', // insert data into catparent node
                );
$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('edtest.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$items = $xpath->query('item');
foreach($items as $item)
{
  $item->appendChild($dom->createElement('catparent', $page_numbers[$item->getAttribute('catcode')]));
}
$dom->save('edtest_new.xml');
?>
```

***My XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
<item>
<catcode>1234</catcode>
<catdesc>Systems - System Bundles</catdesc>
<price_cost>999.95</price_cost>
<price_sell>999.95</price_sell>
</item>
</items>
```

***Output XML***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<items>
<item>
<catcode>1234</catcode>
<catdesc>Systems - System Bundles</catdesc>
<price_cost>999.95</price_cost>
<price_sell>999.95</price_sell>

<catparent></catparent> // it creates but does not insert required data

</item>
</items>
```

It runs the script creates the required node, but it does not insert the required data.  The object of the script is to find `<catcode> = 1234` and add a new `<catparent> </catparent>` with required data from the array.

If there is a better way to achieve the result or just the correction needed.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You're using `$item->getAttribute('catcode')`. However, `catcode` is not an attribute of `<item>`, it's a child element.

Try

```
$catcode = $item->getElementsByTagName('catcode');
$parent_code  = $page_numbers[ $catcode[0] ];

$item->appendChild( $dom->createElement('catparent', $parent_code) );
```

Comment: Thanks but I'm a little lost here so at which point of the script would I insert you code.

Comment: @Karl: In the foreach loop, obviously.

Comment: <?php
$page_numbers = array(
                '1234' => '654', // A Thousand Splendid Suns
                '5678' => '789', // The Brief Wondrous Life of Oscar Wao
        );

$dom = new DOMDocument();
$dom->load('edtest1.xml');
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

$items = $xpath->query('item');
foreach($items as $item)
{
 $catcode = $item->getElementsByTagName('catcode'); $parent_code = $page_numbers[ $catcode[0] ];

 $item->appendChild( $dom->createElement('catparent', $parent_code) );
}

$dom->save('edtest_new.xml');
?>

Comment: Sorry Tomalak I really thought I had got my head round this xml but - well I guess I'm way over my head here.

When I do the above it gives an error at line 15 I dont see an typos

Karl

Comment: So I added your code as above but it gave a error, I changed

'code' $catcode = $item->getElementsByTagName('catcode');



'code' $catcode = $item->getElementsByTagName['catcode'];

<?xml version="1.0"?>
<items>

<item>
<catcode>1234</catcode>
<catdesc>Systems - System Bundles</catdesc>
<catparent></catparent></item>

<item>
<catcode>5678</catcode>
<catdesc>Hard Drives - SATA</catdesc>
<catparent></catparent></item>


</items>

Comment: It nows creates the new xml file with the catparent but still does not insert the data required